# permission denied writing a file on a server

Tags: php

I wish to upload a file from my Android phone to a server on a Raspberry Pi running apache2. I want to do this via php which is not working, so I have reduced the problem to a minimal example which also fails. I think the problem is concerned with permissions.

have the following wtest.php file on the server:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/s$
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<?php
echo 'Current script owner: ' . get_current_user();
echo "\n";

$file2 = fopen('testfile2', 'w');
if ($file2 === false)
{
   print_r(error_get_last());
}
$fwrite2 = fwrite($file2, 'hello');
if ($fwrite2 === false){
    echo "\n";
    echo "write 2 error\n";
}
else{
   echo "write2 OK\n";
}
fclose($file2);
?>
</html>
```

If I access this file from a browser on my PC, I get

```
Current script owner: pi Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => fopen(testfile2): failed to open stream: Permission denied [file] => /var/www/gcm/wtest.php [line] => 8 ) write 2 error
```

If I run what is inside the php tags as a script on the Raspberry Pi server, it works OK. **Temporarily** I have changed the permissions to 777 on the wtest.php and the gcm folder. I  know this is a bad idea for a permananet solution but I have tried it briefly to try and narrow down the problem.

So far, nothing has worked. Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Are you sure if the web server user and the file owner are the same? Would you like to do `chmod 777` on the file that is supposed to be written?

Comment: @PraveenKumar The file to be written doesn't actually exist until the code is executed. The php creates it. It works OK in the script run on the server but not via a browser.

Comment: Check what owner/group php is running under [get_current_user()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php) then set the owner/group of the web folder to the same.

Comment: @Novocaine . When the php is run from a browser, get current_user returns 'pi', as shown in my original post. The gcm folder has its user group shown as pi pi.

Comment: @NickT Can you `chown` the directory to Pi with `chmod 777`?

Comment: It already is owned by pi    /var/www $ ls -la
.
drwxrwxrwx  2 pi   pi    4096 Jul  6 08:01 gcm

Comment: @NickT Any updates? Did anything work or I have a different solution for you. Tell me your PHP version?

Comment: @PraveenKumar - no progress, checked firewall on router, I think that 777 should work no matter what. I think I may have to store the file as a BLOB in mysql, as I know that works OK. My PHP version on the Pi is PHP Version 5.6.22-0+deb8u1

Comment: @NickT Try my solution boss... Tell me please, if it works. This is crazy... It should work! `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the below original code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/s$
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<?php
echo 'Current script owner: ' . get_current_user();
echo "\n";

$file2 = fopen('testfile2', 'w');
if ($file2 === false)
{
   print_r(error_get_last());
}
$fwrite2 = fwrite($file2, 'hello');
if ($fwrite2 === false){
    echo "\n";
    echo "write 2 error\n";
}
else{
   echo "write2 OK\n";
}
fclose($file2);
?>
</html>
```

Please replace the above with `file_put_contents` as it is:

> This function is identical to calling `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()` successively to write data to a file.

```
<?php
if (file_put_contents("testfile2", "hello") !== false)
  echo "File Written";
else
  echo "Failed";
?>
```

Also,

> If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the existing file is overwritten, unless the `FILE_APPEND` flag is set.

**Note:** Just replace the whole file with the above contents. No need of `DocType Definition`.

Comment: Ran it, output was 'Failed'

Comment: I tried it on my Ubuntu laptop with PHP 7 and Apache2. I created a folder and installed the wtest.php. It also failed on that machine. It must be an Apache problem, I had hoped it might be some Raspbian weirdness but apparently not.

Comment: @NickT Can you try creating the file and trying this?

Comment: @NickT Is it writing the right file? Check with `file_exists`?

Comment: Aha, it does work IF I create it first with write permission for user, group and all. Thank you. How to fix it without having an existing file though?

Comment: @NickT `shell_exec("touch testfile2")` Try this?